# Residue Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I've applied the formula  $$\lim_{z \to i} \frac{d}{dz}{(z-z_0)^2.f(z)}$$ and I keep getting a value of 0. Could someone prove my sanity by starting this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with less calculations.

- $f(z) = \frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2} = \frac{z^2+1-2}{(z^2+1)^2}= \frac{1}{z^2+1} - \frac{2}{(z^2+1)^2} $
- $Res_{z=i}\frac{1}{z^2+1} = \lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z-i}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{2i}$
- For $Res_{z=i}\left(- \frac{2}{(z^2+1)^2}\right) = -2 Res_{z=i} \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$ you need to calculate $$\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-i)^2}{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2} = \frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}= \frac{-2}{(z+i)^3} \stackrel{z\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{4i}$$
- All together: $$Res_{z=i}f(z) = \frac{1}{2i} - 2\cdot\frac{1}{4i} = 0$$

p.s.: You can check your residues with wolfram alpha. Here the : [output for above residue](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residuum%20(z%5E2-1)%2F(z%5E2%2B1)%5E2%20at%20z%3Di)

Comment: Thank you, I see what you did!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $f(z)$ has a double pole at $z=i$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=i}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dz}\left((z-i)^2\frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2}\right).
\end{align}

**Edit:** To put you at ease, observe the power series expansion at $z=i$ of the function is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2} =&\ \frac{1}{(z-i)^2}\frac{z^2-1}{(z+i)^2} =\frac{-1}{4(z-i)^2}\frac{(z-i)^2+2i(z-i)-2}{\left(1+\frac{z-i}{2i}\right)^2}\\
=&\ \frac{-1}{4(z-i)^2}\left((z-i)^2+2i(z-i)-2\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)\left(\frac{z-i}{2i} \right)^k\\
=&\ \left(\frac{-1}{4} -\frac{i}{2(z-i)}+\frac{1}{2(z-i)^2}\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)\left(\frac{z-i}{2i} \right)^k\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2(z-i)^2}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}i(z-i)+\text{higher order terms}.
\end{align}
Hence it is clear that the residue is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I did try to do that, but got a zero numberator when I plugged in z=i for the limit.